# Configuração de repositório git com alta disponibilidade usando Helix e Zookeeper

Tags: git, apache, jboss

Preciso configurar um cluster para manter a alta disponibilidade e sincronização de um repositório GIT configurado pelo KIE Workbench. O cenário que eu tenho é o seguinte:

- **VM Máquina 1 - 192.168.33.50** - Ubuntu trusty/64: Servidor do Zookeeper, Helix master,
  Nó do Helix, Jboss + Kieworkbench.
- **VM Máquina 2 - 192.168.33.40** - Ubuntu trusty/64: Nó do Helix, Jboss + Kieworkbench.

Cada máquina executa o Kieworkbench que permite a criação de um repositório GIT. O que eu preciso é que se o repositório for criado em uma máquina do cluster, as informações sejam replicadas na outra máquina, garantindo a transparência de acesso ao usuário que vai poder acessar qualquer uma das máquinas e visualizar o mesmo repositório GIT. Em minhas pesquisas, vi que é possível fazer isso utilizando o Apache Zookeeper + Apache Helix [[1](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#wb.WorkbenchHighAvailability)][[2](https://opensourcebpm.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/redhat-jboss-bpms-design-time-clustering/)]. O problema é que mesmo depois de seguir os tutoriais, ainda não consegui o alcançar o comportamento desejado.

O que eu fiz até o momento, de forma resumida:

- Máquina 1

  1. Instalação do Zookeeper, Helix, Jboss + kieworkbench, Java 6.
  2. Configuração do profile standalone-full-ha do Jboss para esse nó do cluster.

     ```
     <system-properties>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.dir" value="/usr/src/jboss/bin"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.enabled" value="true"/>
     <property name="org.kie.demo" value="false"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.host" value="192.168.33.50"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.port" value="9418"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.enabled" value="true"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.host" value="192.168.33.50"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.port" value="8001"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.zk" value="192.168.33.50:2181"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.local.id" value="192.168.33.50_11"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.vfs.lock" value="vfs-repo"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.metadata.index.dir" value="/usr/src/jboss/bin"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.autostart" value="false"/>
     </system-properties>
     ```
  3. Execução do zookeeper server e configuração dos nós do cluster:

     ```
     sh zkServer.sh start
     ./helix-admin.sh -zkSvr 192.168.33.50:2181 -addCluster bpmCluster
     ./helix-admin.sh -zkSvr 192.168.33.50:2181 -addNode bpmCluster 192.168.33.50:11
     ./helix-admin.sh -zkSvr 192.168.33.50:2181 -addNode bpmCluster 192.168.33.40:22
     ./helix-admin.sh -zkSvr 192.168.33.50:2181 -addResource bpmCluster vfs-repo 1 LeaderStandby AUTO_REBALANCE
     ./helix-admin.sh -zkSvr 192.168.33.50:2181 -rebalance bpmCluster vfs-repo 2
     ./run-helix-controller.sh -zkSvr 192.168.33.50:2181 -cluster bpmCluster 2>&1 > ./controller.log &
     ```
  4. Inicialização do Jboss

     ```
     ./standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b 192.168.33.50 &
     ```
- Máquina 2

  1. Instalação do Helix e Jboss.
  2. Configuração do profile standalone-full-ha do Jboss para esse nó do cluster.

     ```
     <system-properties>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.dir" value="/usr/src/jboss/bin"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.enabled" value="true"/>
     <property name="org.kie.demo" value="false"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.host" value="192.168.33.40"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.port" value="9418"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.enabled" value="true"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.host" value="192.168.33.40"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.port" value="8001"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.zk" value="192.168.33.50:2181"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.local.id" value="192.168.33.40_22"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.vfs.lock" value="vfs-repo"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.metadata.index.dir" value="/usr/src/jboss/bin"/>
     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.autostart" value="false"/>
     ```
  3. Execução do controlador do nó do Helix

     ```
     ./run-helix-controller.sh -zkSvr 192.168.33.50:2181 -cluster bpmCluster 2>&1 > ./controller.log &
     ```
  4. Inicialização do Jboss

     ```
     ./standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b 192.168.33.40 &
     ```

Ainda sim não ocorre a sincronização dos dados. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Eu entendi errado o uso dessas ferramentas de alta disponibilidade? Esqueci de alguma configuração?